# Verify my proof of divisibility of a rational fraction

Tags: proof-verification, rational-functions

I tried to prove that the following rational fraction can be divided only when n=1,2,5 without using mathematical induction or function, just by using basic method. $$\frac{n^2+2}{2n-1}$$  this expression can be divided only when the remainder of $$\frac{n^2}{2n-1}$$ is $$\frac{2n-3}{2n-1}$$ and the quotient of the following expression $$\frac{n^2}{2n-1}$$ has the same quotient with the following expression, except in the case of n=1$$\frac{n^2}{2n}$$ because when some dividend is divided by these two different divisor, in order to $$2n-1$$ has much more quotient than $$2n$$ It's necessary to meet particular condition that when dividend is greater than or equal to $$2n$$ also when the dividend is greater than or equal to $$(2n)(2n-1)$$ then $$2n-1$$ can has much more quotient than $$2n$$ and when the dividend is less than $$2n$$ also when the value of the dividend is equal to the value of $$2n-1$$ then $$2n-1$$ can has much more quotient than $$2n$$ So $$n^2$$ is greater than or equal to $$2n$$ except when n=1, and when n=1, the value of $$n^2$$ is less than $$2n$$ and is equal to the value of $$2n-1$$ So when n=1, $$2n-1$$ has much more quotient than $$2n$$ and when n>1, $$n^2$$ is greater than or equal to $$2n$$ and is less than $$(2n)(2n-1)$$ So $$\frac{n^2}{2n-1}$$ has the same quotient with $$\frac{n^2}{2n}$$ except in the case of n=1. and $$\frac{n^2}{2n}=\frac{n}{2}$$ so the quotient of $$\frac{n}{2}$$ can be expressed by a formula $$\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{4}$$ and in the following expression$$\frac{n}{2}$$ when n is even number there is no remainder and when n is odd number the remainder is always $$\frac{1}{2}$$ It also can be expressed as $$\frac{n}{2n}$$ and in the following expression $$\frac{n^2}{2n-1}$$ when n is even number the remainder of the expression is as much as Its quotient. and when n is odd number the remainder of the division is $$n+quotient$$ now I can answer the question about when the remainder become $$2n-3$$ is, by using the formula $$\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{4}$$ when n is even number It can be expressed as $$\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{4}=2n-3$$ this equation can be changed into $$12-(1+(-1)^{n+1})=6n$$ by multiplying both sides by 4 and by transposition. and when n is odd number, It can be expressed as $$n+\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{4}=2n-3$$ this equation can be changed into $$12-(1+(-1)^{n+1})=2n$$ so, the following expression $$\frac{n^2+2}{2n-1}$$ is can be divided only when n=2,5 but this equation works only when n>1. and when=1 the expression can be divided. so this is what I tried to prove the question. I wanna know this proof is correct or incorrect, Could you please check my proof? roughly If you want. and I wanna know this kind of approach is proper or not when I'm gonna study advanced mathematics.

Comment: "devided" should be "divided". You have some other typos -- but this one jumps out as being systematic, so I thought that you would want to know.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you for Proofreading! and Thank you for Compliment! I will keep trying my best!!! Thank you!

Comment: @Qsigma Thank you for editting my article!

Comment: And Yes! I really wanted to know :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest the following approach :

First consider $(2n-1)(2n+1)=4n^2-1$ hence we have $$4\cdot \frac{n^2+2}{2n-1}=\frac{4n^2+8}{2n-1}=\frac{4n^2-1}{2n-1}+\frac{9}{2n-1}=2n+1+\frac{9}{2n-1}$$

Since $2n-1$ is odd, it must divide $n^2+2$ , if it divides $4(n^2+2)$ (try to find out why), hence you only have to check for which $n$ we have $2n-1|9$. Try to solve this.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you for answering my question and giving me very interesting problem. I'm gonna try to solve this problem that you gave to me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

By long division,

$$\frac{n^2+2}{2n-1}=\frac n2+\frac14+\frac9{4(2n-1)}$$ or
$$4\frac{n^2+2}{2n-1}=2n+1+\frac9{2n-1}$$
so that $2n-1$ must divide $9$ and $n$ could be $1,2$ or $5$, which turn out to all be valid solutions.

If negatives are allowed, consider $0,-1,-4$ which are also possible.

Comment: Thank you!! Your answer is very helpful as well!!

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to get the answer:

If $2n - 1$ divides $n^2 + 2$ then there is an integer $k$ such that
$n^2 + 2 = k(2n - 1),$
that is, 
$$ n^2 - 2kn + (k + 2) = 0.$$
Solving this as a quadratic equation in $n,$
\begin{align}
n &= \frac{2k \pm \sqrt{4k^2 - 4(k + 2)}}{2} \\
 &= k \pm \sqrt{k^2 - k - 2)},
\end{align}
which is possible only if $k^2 - k - 2 = m^2$ 
for some non-negative integer $m.$
Observing that $k^2 - k - 2 = (k - 2)(k + 1),$
the product can be a square only if it is non-negative, that is,
$k \geq 2$ or $k \leq = -1.$

If $k \geq 2$ then $m \leq k - 1$; it follows that 
$m^2 \leq k^2 - 2k + 1,$ and therefore
$$k^2 - k - 2 \leq k^2 - 2k + 1.$$
Canceling the $k^2$ terms and collecting the other terms appropriately, this is equivalent to $k \leq 3.$ We can check that $k = 2$ and $k = 3$ both are valid solutions.

If $k \leq -1,$ let $p = -k$; then $p \geq 1$ and $m^2 = p^2 + p - 2,$
which has solution $m = 0$ if $p = 1,$ solution $m = 2$ if $p = 2,$
and otherwise $m \geq p + 1,$ so $m^2 \geq p^2 + 2p + 1,$
so $p^2 + p - 2 \geq p^2 + 2p + 1,$ so $-p \geq 3,$ but that contradicts the case assumption that $k \leq -1.$
Hence there are no other solutions.

So the solutions are $k = 2,$ $k = 3,$ $k = -1,$ and $k = -2$.
The possible values of $n$ therefore are given in this table:
\begin{array}{ccccl}
 k  &\qquad k^2 - k - 2 \qquad&  &n& \\ \hline
\phantom{-}2  &  4 - 2 - 2 = 0  &  2 \pm \sqrt0 &=& 2, \\
\phantom{-}3  &  9 - 3 - 2 = 4  &  3 \pm \sqrt4 &=& 1 \text{ or } 5, \\
-1  &  1 - (-1) - 2 = 0  &  -1 \pm \sqrt0 &=& -1, \\
-2  &  4 - (-2) - 2 = 4  &  -2 \pm \sqrt4 &=& 0 \text{ or } -4.
\end{array}

---

It's easier to solve $2n - 1 \mid 9,$ so I would go with one of the other solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your very specific and very helpful answer!!